# Users Unable To Load Website or Even Leave Server Log When Visiting Specifically from An iPhone/iPad (Any Browser)

Tags: ios, iphone, wordpress, nginx

I became aware of this issue soon after migrating the site from one hosting account (Media Temple) to another (InMotion).

Ultimately the site renders completely fine on all desktop browsers and all mobile devices other than iPhone/iPads, but any kind of browser on an iPhone or iPad is unable to connect (I've tested Chrome, Safari, Firefox).

This is specific to these actual devices - I can render the website just fine on browser-based mobile device emulators, and simulating Apple products using Chrome Development Tool.

The hosting company wasn't able to offer any insight and mentioned that the IP addresses of iPad/iPhone users don't even hit our weblogs or generate any sort of error he can see and that ultimately the IP address from the Apple device I was using to test isn't present in any logs.

Briefly, I did see an error in Safari Desktop that read:

NSPOSIXErrorDomain:100

At this point I'm planning to migrate the site back to the original host to see if that is a possible solution, but ultimately I'm just at a loss as to why iPad/iPhone devices are affected and not leaving any logs.

The site itself I did not develop, but is Wordpress based and I have tried turning off the plugins, switching themes, and retesting on my mobile device but I wasn't able to fix that error.

The domain can be found [here](http://licenselounge.com)

Would appreciate any insight.

Comment: To share some more insight I was able to confirm that the HTTP version of the internal pages are loading on apple mobile devices.  I did implement this fix which did not help the issue but seems to be related to the issue at hand:

Comment: Whoops took too much time editing:I have also cleared all local, WP, and server caches as well as tested the problem at different WIFI networks.  The site itself (running Wordpress, Easy Digital Downloads, a few custom plugins I cannot update) was still showing this mobile iOS issue when disabling all plugins, as well as switching themes.Due to the HTTP loading (internal pages only) I am going to focus on the SSL and see whether switching certs will fix the issue, as well as confirming HTTP/2 is being used.

Comment: Fix I tried: https://help.poralix.com/articles/iphone-does-not-open-https-site-safari-nsposixerrordomain